# Объединить два SQL запроса в один

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Использую MySQL+PHP
Как объединить два следующих SELECT в один запрос?

```
SELECT `users` FROM `my_table` WHERE `id`=?
```

далее мне нужно в этой же таблице найти все записи с этим же `users`

```
SELECT `number` FROM `my_table` WHERE `users`=?
```

Comment: Если у вас одна и таже таблица то данные можно получить одним запросом.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что вы подразумеваете под "объединить"? Чего вы хотите добиться? А главное зачем?

Comment: просто с PHP (PDO) мне придется подготавливать два запроса и два execute(). Получается нагрузка на сервер больше. (и кода тоже). Два ответа ниже мне подошли. только последний я пока не проверил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если результат должен соотвествовать обоим условиям

```
SELECT `users`, `numbers` FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = ? AND `users` = ?
```

Если результат должен соотвествовать хотя бы одному условию

```
SELECT `users`, `numbers` FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = ? OR `users` = ?
```

Если надо найти `numbers` по найденому `users`

```
SELECT `numbers` FROM `my_table` WHERE `users` = (SELECT `users` FROM `my_table` WHERE id = ?)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select t2.* -- или t2.users, t2.number если надо только эти два поля
  from my_table t1
  join my_table t2 on t2.users = t1.users
 where t1.id = ?
```

Comment: спасибо, но если я ищу в одной таблице

Comment: Но там и так одна таблица. my_table. Других нет. Используется широко распространённый приём объединения с самой  собой

Comment: тогда t1 и t2 что такое? сначала попробую из первого ответа последний вариант

Comment: Это псевдонимы. Задаются чтобы 1) не писать длинные имена таблиц, 2) чтобы можно было использовать в запросе одну и туже таблицу сколь угодно раз

Comment: Спасибо! Я думаю ваш ответ более грамотный, но верхний вариант более понятный (воспользовался им). Обязательно заставлю себя разобраться с `JOIN` (пока ни как не могу представить что происходит). Вопрос: ваш запрос с верхним по скорости одинаково работают?

Comment: Наверное одинаково. точно не знаю.

Comment: @Freqnsy зависит от размера таблицы, чем больше данных тем дольше будет работать JOIN

Comment: Вот тут обсасывается вопрос подзапросов и жоинов http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query в первую очередь с точки зрения производительности (ибо вопрос именно об этом) и какая форма является более логичной.